# Encoding error in dupe check function

Tags: python-3.x, mmap

I have a function I want to use to check if a string is already contained in a given file.

The function looks like this:

```
def check_dupe(filename, word):
    print(filename)
    print(word)
    with open(filename, 'rb', 0) as file, mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
        if s.find(word.encode()) != -1:
            print('dupe')
            return True
```

I get the following error:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='links' mode='r' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checker.py", line 277, in <module>
    main()
  File "checker.py", line 261, in main
    text_links = [line.strip() for line in f if not check_dupe('completed_links', f)]
  File "checker.py", line 261, in <listcomp>
    text_links = [line.strip() for line in f if not check_dupe('completed_links', f)]
  File "checker.py", line 240, in check_dupe
    if s.find(word.encode()) != -1:
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Where does your `word` comes from ? (the one passed as parameter to `check_dupe()`). I guess you assume that it is a string, but the stackstrace shows that it is a `_io.TextIOWrapper`

Comment: Additionnal questions: is your file a text file, or binary content ? And is there any specific reason for you to use `mmap` ?

Comment: @Guillaume It is 100% a string, I checked with `type()`. Yes, word is passed as an argument. The reason I am using mmap is because I found it to be faster than other methods. The file is a normal text file, but read as binary. If you have a quicker way to check a file for a word I am open to suggestions.

Comment: No, it is 100% a `_io.TextIOWrapper` :) see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just by reading the stackstrace, bottom to top:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='links' mode='r' encoding='ANSI_X3.4-1968'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checker.py", line 277, in <module>
    main()
  File "checker.py", line 261, in main
    text_links = [line.strip() for line in f if not check_dupe('completed_links', f)]
  File "checker.py", line 261, in <listcomp>
    text_links = [line.strip() for line in f if not check_dupe('completed_links', f)]
  File "checker.py", line 240, in check_dupe
    if s.find(word.encode()) != -1:
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

`word` is a `_io.TextIOWrapper` and you try to call its non-existing `encode()` method.

`word` is the parameter that you pass to your `check_dupe()` function there, line 261:

```
[line.strip() for line in f if not check_dupe('completed_links', f)]
```

you pass `f` as parameter for `word`, and `f` is the file that you read your lines from. I guess it is a file opened with open("filename") which returns `_io.TextIOWrapper`

I guess you meant to pass `line` as parameter instead, which is indeed a string:

```
[line.strip() for line in f if not check_dupe('completed_links', line)]
```